# How can I monitor queue buffer of ovs or Physical switches?

Tags: switch-statement, queue, buffer, openvswitch

I have set two queues in a port .I want to know how many packets are waiting in the queues .now I can only get the tx_packets of a queue ,can I get rx_packets of a queue? or,do you have a way to get the space has been used in a queue?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: hello,I am trying to do something with ovs source code to get the length of queue.

Answer (score 0):

Due to issues like Microbursts, and the fact that they are processed at the speed of light, capturing the moment of a problem or overflow in such queues with a query-based monitoring system is almost impossible or requires extreme luck. Only mechanisms called "lossless" have been developed in the TCP and Ethernet layers for these issues. The chip knowing that the queue is full generates some flow control packets at the Ethernet or TCP layer. This leads to a warning-level log being written both on the switch/router and host side, and very rarely, statistics being added. My advice would be to read up on PFC, Congestion Control, and DCBX.